# JavaScript increasing variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add ID to each element of class `.content`, and I want each ID to have integer increase by 1. Example:

```
<div class="content" id="content_1"></div>
<div class="content" id="content_2"></div>
```

etc. I wrote code which looks like this:

```
var number = 1;
$(".content").each(function() { 
    $('.content').attr('id', 'content_' + number);
    number++;
});
```

This code adds `content_2` to both of them rather than `content_1` and `content_2`, if I have 3 elements with `.content` class all of them will have an ID of `content_3`

Any ideas how I could fix that?

Comment: Inside your foreach, you have a function that changes all the items having the class "content". So, all your items will always have the same ID in the end

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `this` in the each loop :

```
$(".content").each(function(index) { 
    this.id = 'content_' + index;
});
```

Otherwise you are selecting all the elements with class `.content`

JS only approach:

```
var content = document.querySelectorAll('.content');

[].forEach.call(content, function(item, index) {
  item.id = "content_" + (index+1);
});
```

ES6/ES2015 syntax:

```
let content = document.querySelectorAll('.content');

[].forEach.call(content, (item, index) => item.id = `content_${(index+1)}`);
```

Comment: Oh wow, yeah I completely forgot about this! Thanks for making it quick! =]

Comment: Unless you need a unique number across multiple `.each()` there is no reason to have a `number` variable, and instead just `each(function(index) { this.id = "content_" + index })`.  [jQuery.each(function(Integer index, Element element))](https://api.jquery.com/each/).

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
var number = 1;
$(".content").each(function() { 
    this.id = 'content_' + number;
    number++;
});
```

Note: you could just use vanilla JS to assign the attribute `id` (no need to use jQuery)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the index parameter of the [.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function callback instead of your own counter:

```
$(".content").each(function(i) {
  $(this).prop('id', 'content_' + (i+1));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this operator

```
    var number = 1;
$(".content").each(function() { 
    $('.content').attr('id', 'content_' + number);
    number++;
});
```

or

```
var length = $(".content").length;

for(i=1;i<length;i++){

    $('.content')[i].attr('id', 'content_' + i);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var number = 1;
$(".content").each(function() { 
    this.id = 'content_' + number++;
});
```

This is iterate single elements one by one rather than taking all elements with .content